# How can I execute the function when I press the button in React Native?

Tags: react-native, axios, formik

I'm trying to execute a function (Save) which makes a post request to my API in Node js; this request is using Axios. In the form, I'm using Formik and Yup for validations. The form is a simple login. And I have been following this blog:

https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-form-validations-with-formik-and-yup/

And obviously, the documentation of Formik, Yup, Axios, and React Native.

The problem is that the Save funtion does not execute, simply does not work. When I press the button the function does not run.

When I use

`console.log(values)`

I get all the values. However, when I use:

`Save(values)`

The function does not execute.

I could see in Formik Doc that I needed use this on the button component

```
onPress={handleSubmit}
```

But it does not work either.

I'm doing the same as the blog author did. I think the handleSubmit function is own of the library and I would dont have to add something else, but actually I'm not sure.

In here the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import Background from './../../components/Background';
import { API } from "./../../config/config";
import Btn from './../../components/Btn';

const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
        .min(6, "Demasiado corto")
        .max(100, "Demasiado largo")
        .email("No corresponde a un email válido.")
        .required("Requerido"),
    pwd: Yup.string()
        .min(8, "Demasiado corto")
        .max(100, "Demasiado largo")
        .required("Requerido"),
});

const Login = (props) => {

    const loginform = {
        email: '',
        pwd: ''
    }

    const Save = (value) => {
        console.log(value);
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${API}/login`,
            data: {
                email: value.email,
                pwd: value.pwd
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            let data = response.data;
            if (data.OK === true) {
                alert("Bienvenido " + data.User.Usuario[0].NombreCompleto);
                props.navigation.navigate("Home")
                AsyncStorage.setItem(
                    'TOKEN',
                    data.TOKEN,
                );
            } else {
                if (data.OK === false) {
                    Alert(data.message, 2)
                }
            }
        }).catch((e) => {
            let error = e.message;
            if (error.OK === false) {
                alert(error.message)
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <Background>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', width: 460 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginRight: 50, marginTop: 100 }}>
                    <Image source={require('./../../assets/Logo.png')} />
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        felx: 1,
                        height: 700,
                        width: '100%',
                        paddingTop: 40,
                        marginRight: 50,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}>
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={loginform}
                        validationSchema={LoginSchema}
                        onSubmit={values => console.log(values) }
                    >
                        {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, touched, isValid, }) => (
                            <View>
                                <TextInput
                                    name="email"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                                    onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                                    value={values.email}
                                    keyboardType="email-address"
                                    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 30, backgroundColor: 'white', marginVertical: 10, width: '60%' }}
                                    placeholderTextColor='gray'>
                                </TextInput>
                                {(errors.email && touched.email) &&
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.email}</Text>
                                }
                                <TextInput
                                    name="pwd"
                                    placeholder="Contraseña"
                                    onChangeText={handleChange('pwd')}
                                    onBlur={handleBlur('pwd')}
                                    value={values.pwd}
                                    secureTextEntry={true}
                                    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 30, backgroundColor: 'white', marginVertical: 10, width: '60%' }}
                                    placeholderTextColor='gray'>
                                </TextInput>
                                {(errors.pwd && touched.pwd) &&
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.pwd}</Text>
                                }
                                <View
                                    style={{ alignItems: 'flex-start', width: '60%', paddingRight: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("RecuperarPWD")}>
                                        <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>
                                            ¿Olvidó su contraseña?
                                        </Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                                <Button style={{ color: 'white', width: 200, backgroundColor: '#FF8029'}} onPress={handleSubmit} title="Iniciar Sesión" disabled={!isValid}/>
                            </View>
                        )}
                    </Formik>
                    <View style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "center" }}>
                        <Btn textColor='white' width={365} bgColor='#FF8029' mt={120} mr={15} btnLabel="¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? ¡Registrate!" Press={() => props.navigation.navigate("Registro")} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Background>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Thanks and I look forward to your help

Comment: You're stating that you used `Save(Values)` the v is uppercase when using the `console.log(values)` its lowercase

Comment: @RubenSmn, Sorry. It was an error here while I was writing the problem description. In the code it is with v, in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

using onSubmit

```
<Formik
    ...
    onSubmit={Save}
>
```

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. Well, with this, the program run the Save function. I tried something like this before:
 onSubmit={values = Save(values)}
 but It did not work. I don't know why. Anyway.
The problem now is that the program does not execute the axios part, so, it does not make the post request. Any idea?

Comment: try copying the Save function inside onSubmit

Comment: It still does not work 

Comment: change to use useFormilk

Comment: I changed it but it was the same. Later I found a Network Error in Axios, so I was searching about that error and I found that I needed to have the IP instead of localhost in my URL, and with that the program is working now. But, Thanks a lot.

Comment: try using axios version 0.27.2